# Any source for Shimano shoelaces?

Tags: shoes, shopping

I have a pair of Shimano SPD-compatible shoes that have served me well and have a couple more years of good service in them.  But the shoelaces are about to disintegrate.

I've looked online and at several stores for replacements, but can't find anything to match.  The existing laces are round and relatively soft, whereas most round laces one finds are either thin dress laces or heavy, stiff boot laces.  The boot laces don't tie as easily and don't stay tied nearly as well.  Besides, I like the look of the original Shimano laces.

Has anyone found a source for the "real thing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the exact laces are available under the Shimano brand, but the internet may prove me wrong.

The closest thing I have found online is oval athletic laces like these:

[image: oval athletic laces]

When I replaced mine I found similar laces at a sporting goods store, but I've seen similar sport laces at some of the big box stores as well. If you google "oval athletic laces" you should find a large number of online sellers as well.

Comment: Thanks -- those look better than anything I've found so far.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks - Whatabout 'New Balance' reflective laces, available in a variety of colours and lengths?

Comment: Something like the above image is what I eventually purchased.  Not a perfect replacement for the Shimano laces, but reasonably close.

Answer (score 3):

I've replaced my original round Shimano laces with flat laces, I found at my local shoe repair shop. I explained them, I need them for sports and they gave me special weather resistant laces. They last longer as the original laces.

The round laces I found, loosened the knot too fast. And also didn't last long enough. The flat laces keep the knot good, and don't make a big knot so they are comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I use flat laces for my shimanos - they never come undone and they were about £3 at Clark's shoe shop:-)